# scope() function returning undefined in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, return-value

I have a function inside controller:

```
$scope.passValues = function (param1){
    return "foo";
};
console.log($scope.passValues());
```

this will log `foo`, but:

```
$scope.passValues = function (param1){
    return param1;
};
console.log($scope.passValues());
```

this 
I don't understand why because:

```
$scope.passValues = function (param1){
        console.log(param1);
        return param1;
     };
```

will log `robert`, which is coorect when used as `passValues(item.firstName)`.
My problem is with second example, where I need the function to correctly return param1 value so it can be used later in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why the downgrade this was a legitimate question and here is the answer, I think I got misunderstood or gave bad explanation.

I had to use a service, to use param1 in another controller:

first controller:

```
  $scope.passValues = function (param1){
      myservice.firstName = param1;
 };
```

the service:

```
.service('myservice', function() {
})
```

The second controller:

```
  .controller('detail',
    function ($scope, myservice) {
        $scope.content = myservice.firstName;

    });
```

then on the template, {{content}} correctly displays value of param1 (firstName).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to pass a value to your function, otherwise the argument will be `undefined`

from controller

```
$scope.passValues('Robert')
```

And from your view

```
<div>
{{ passValues('Robert') }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came to this question when I was trying to search for possible reasons of `scope()` to return undefined...

in my case, I had a module `myApp` with `MyController` with `$scope.reloadItems` function:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyController' id="myAngularApp">
```

js files that I was loading for this:

- `angular.min.js`, `ng-infinite-scroll.min.js`
- my `my_angular_app.js` with definition of my module
- and `some_view.js` where I was doing:

  ```
  $('#myAngularApp').scope().reloadItems();
  ```

Now the `scope()` often returns `undefined` when module can not be instantiated or there is some error. In this case it was because of **order, in which I loaded .js files**, because of which:
`$('#myAngularApp').scope()` was executed before the `my_angular_app.js` had a chance to build this module...

... so in case someone else comes here like me, I hope this will help :)